# how we can reflect one project commits in other projects using SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn, repository, svnsync

We have Product **A** and 2 projects say **B,C**.

**B** & **C** are other projects which are having complete **A** product functionality and added some other extra functionality which are specific to **B** & **C**.

**My Problem:**

If i will commit any code in **A** it should get update in **B** & **C** as they are having complete replica of A with some other features.

**Note:** All are in same repository(SVN) but different projects.

If there is any way to do this, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming projects B and C are branches off of product A, what you will need to do periodically is merge changes across from B or C to A, and vice versa.

Read up on Chapter 4 of the SVN Book, [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html).

Comment: Thank you for the replay. B and C are completely different projects, not in branches. I am finding a way to automate this merging from product A to B & C, not vice versa.

Comment: Since you mentioned that B and C are essentially supersets of A, you should consider creating branches for them off A, and apply the extra functionality manually (this is a once-off, purely so Subversion can begin tracking the parent-child relationship). Then, when A gets updated, all you'd need to do is merge it across to B and C.